# How to read a large csv(2.5GB) into R?

Tags: r, csv, import, large-data

I have read a lot of posts in stackoverflow about reading large files into R. 
My data is arond 2.5GB with ~30,000,000 rows and ~15columns. 
I tried the sqldf method which is from other's post,

```
library(sqldf)
f <- file("~/Downloads/data.csv")
system.time(bigdf <- sqldf("select * from f", dbname = tempfile(), file.format = list(header = T, row.names = F)))
```

which returned an error indicating that

```
"RS-DBI driver: (RS_sqlite_import: /Users/data.csv line 14691020 expected 13 columns of data but found 1)"
```

Does anyone have other good methods?

Update:
I just tried the ff package, which still did not work.

```
library(ff)
system.time(read.csv.ffdf(file="~/Downloads/data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=','))
```

it returned an error as well,

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
scan() expected 'an integer', got '"18749362"'
```

**Solution:**

I tried ff, fread, sqldf, colClass, all these methods do not work. Thus, I find a file splitting application online, which easily solve my problem. 
Thank you all for answering my question!

***This question is closed.***

Comment: Take a look at `ff` package for example.

Comment: I tried ff and it did not work as well.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest patched version of R and if needed fix your data.

Comment: my first idea was 'fread' from data.table, see e.g. http://www.r-bloggers.com/efficiency-of-importing-large-csv-files-in-r/

Comment: The problem, as the error message is telling you, is that there are irregularities in your data format that need to be fixed or adjusted for.

Comment: But since the file is so large, if I want to find the error, I also need to load my data first into R. And it came to my question. I am so confusing now.

Comment: is r the only tool you may use?

Comment: Not true. The first error message told you the line number it occurred on. All you need is a text editor and some patience.

Comment: Thank you @joran. I will try to find the line. Actually it is difficult for me because it also takes me for a long time to open the file with text editor. Do you have any recommendations? Thank you so much!

Comment: @rawr I also can use Access. And after loading the data, the next thing I am going to do is to merge the data with another data frame. So, do you think it is a good way to use nature join in Access?

Comment: I think you should avoid microsoft office anything when working with a lot of data (or any amount of data in general). the newest excel, IIRC, can only handle a million rows, for example

Comment: @rawr Thank you for your information. So, do you have any recommendations such as SRS or STATA?